# How are the CLLocationmanger delegate methods arecalled when the application is in background mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, core-location

How can I get the CLLocationManager delegate methods, when the app gone into background,

I am new to `CLLocationManager`

Actually my app gets called CLLocationmanager dalegate methods when the app is running in the foreground but when the app goes into the background those are not called.

By using

```
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
```

method my app get called these methods

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {
    NSLog(@"Entered Region");
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {
    NSLog(@"Exited Region");
}
```

How can I use the `CLLocationmanagerdelegate` in the `appDelegate` class?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the background modes in the app's plist to include location services?

Comment: yes I have also same  problem. And am set in the plist like "Required background modes to App registers for location updates" but not solved..can any one help?.... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360386/didenterregion-works-in-foreground-but-not-background-or-other-vcs) as they are quite related.

Basically, creating a singleton CLLocationManager solved the problem.